# find out char's sequences in array

Tags: c

It has been a long time that I have not dealt with arrays in C.

So I need to find multiple string's sequences in char's array 
in fact I need them for parsing some command lines

example:

```
char *myArray=" go where:\"here\" when:\"i dont know ...\";
```

I need to find out what are the specified parameter when app  runs 
I have done some functions but the  result is weird

```
void splitString(char *from ,char start ,char end ,char *into)
{
    int size=strlen(from);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(from[i]==start)
        {
            for(int j=i;j<size;j++){
                if(from[j]!=end)
                    into+=from[j];
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }

}
```

and the call

```
char *into;
char *from="this is #string# i want to look for ";
splitString(from,'#','#',into);
```

result in [the following dialog](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-KOATOhokM2k/UFxQGLsAYbI/AAAAAAAAAEo/8wKkJEnReoY/s320/weird.png)

Comment: don't you need to create `into` (with `char* into = new char[SIZE];`) before accessing it via the `[]` operator?

Comment: @Default There's no `new[]` in C. There is `malloc()` though, which certainly applies here.

Comment: @unwind that's what I get for knowing C++ but not C. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three main problems with your code.

The first is that the line

```
into+=from[j];
```

doesn't copy the character, it increases the local pointer. See the answer from kTekkie how to solve that. The second is that you don't terminate the string you copy to, which is also in the answer from kTekkie.

The third major problem is that you don't allocate memory for the `into` variable, so when you start to properly copy characters, you will copy into whatever `into` points to, which will be a random memory location. This is undefined behavior and will most likely cause your program to crash. To solve this either create `into` as an array like

```
char into[SOME_SIZE];
```

or to dynamically allocate memory on the heap with `malloc`

```
char *into = malloc(SOME_SIZE);
```

If you go for the dynamic allocation, remember to `free` the allocated memory when you don't need it any more.

**Edit:** Taking a close look at the function...

There are a few other problems with your function, besides the ones described above in my answer. One is that you have a `break` statement in the outer loop, so it will step out of the loop immediately.

I would actually write it something like this:

```
void splitString(char *from, char start, char end, char *into)
{
    /* Really first we make sure the output string can be printed by terminating it */
    *into = '\0';

    /* First find the `start` character */
    while (*from && *from++ != start)
        ;

    /* Now we are either at the end of the string, or found the character */
    if (!*from)
        return;  /* At end of string, character not found */

    /* Copy the string while we don't see the `end` character */
    while (*from && *from != end)
        *into++ = *from++;

    /* Now terminate the output string */
    *into = '\0';
}
```

It works, as can be seen [here](http://ideone.com/rQ4Bk). The previous link also shows how to call it.

Comment: yea i did but by giving size to my array but still same stuff

Comment: @meroummxm I rewrote your function, please see my edited answer.

Comment: lol the whole program crashed down i don't know if there is  differences between pure C/C++ and VC++ because i'm working with it    plus i have tried a small test

Comment: `void changeV(char * v){
v="this is the new value";

}
char *old="this is the old thing ";   changeV(old);` the result is this is the old thing what is that i don't understand

Comment: @meroummxm Debugger debugger debugger debugger! :)

Comment: i'm not debugging i  run it as release and as exe the same stuff

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to terminate into string when the data is received.  and just increment j to i+1

```
void splitString(char *from ,char start ,char end ,char *into)
{
  int k = 0;
  int size=strlen(from);
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
    if(from[i]==start)
    {
        for(int j=i+1, k = 0;j<size;j++, k++){
            if(from[j]!=end)
                into[k]=from[j];
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    break;
}

into[k] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: first at all K variable is local which means not known at the end **into[k] = '\0';** plus that is there any way to avoid thrid variable

Answer (score -1):

Today's topic: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I don't think that cplusplus.com would change, but OK.

Comment: another argument can be found [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) - basically *When someone goes on StackOverflow, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer. You should provide context to all your links, otherwise the OP will have no idea what they are clicking into.

It's also a way of saying "I have absolutely no value beyond a google Bing search" Which is completely untrue, so why sell yourself short?*

Comment: And what's the point to make string split function when you can use existing one? On the reference site all is thoroughly explained so even beginner could know how to use strtok. So sorry but I don't agree with your hate.

Comment: strtok isn't my need i'm parsing command line  like what u do in shell  ls -l or rm -r etc .. do u see